# Change default NullProcessing setting for a cube or project in BIDS

Tags: ssas, bids

Simple question - is there a way to change the default NullProcessing setting from Automatic to Preserve?

When you have a measure with NULL values in some rows these NULL values are by default changed to 0 due to the default NULLProcessing setting. I would like to change this setting, so the default value is Preserve.

Kind Regards,
Søren

Comment: I might add that I am using SQL Server 2008R2

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Change the NullProcessing property for the measure(s) to Preserve. You can find this in the properties window when you expand Source folder. Preserve is the first of four available options.

Comment: I know you can change this setting on each measure one by one. But I want change the default, so when I create a new measure NullProcessing is set to Preserve and not Automatic. Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough.